# Best way to use SQL trigger with conditional count to audit database reports?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, triggers

I'm looking to implementing a trigger in my SQL server to save report edits as they are being made.

The server operates a report/dictation software package. Basically a "report_text" draft is created by user1, then edited by user2 before being finalized by user2. The drafts of user1 are saved to a table and overwritten with every save in the database, once user1 is finished and user2 makes edits, the data is further overwritten. So, the final draft of user1 is lost once user2 saves their edits.

I am trying to save the "report_text" to a new table once user1 is finished.

A separate table keeps an audit log with a report_id, access_time, and user who has accessed the report. New rows are inserted to the audit table for every access until finalized, so that each report_id in the audit table can have anywhere from 2 to 4 lines (depending on the number of users who have accessed the file before being finalized). The trigger should capture the "report_text" when the number of rows for each report_id in the audit table for each report_id changes from 2 to 3.

```
USE SERVER
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER trigger [dbo].[prelim_text_trigger]
on [dbo].[report_to_user]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO
dbo.report_compare (report_id)

SELECT report_id
FROM inserted
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(report_id) 
FROM report_to_user 
GROUP BY report_id 
HAVING count(report_id) > 2);

END
```

I tried the following code without success. Nothing was inserted into `dbo.report_compare` and there were issues with the audit table `dbo.report_to_user` while the trigger was running. I think the trigger failed and transaction were being rolled back.

What am I doing wrong? Should I have made a conditional statement so that if the condition isn't met the transaction proceeds? Does this accurately count the whole table for the number of instances report_id is present, or is it counting just from the temporary table `from inserted`?

Going forward, if the trigger fails I would like the transactions to continue. If I add `XACT_ABORT OFF` or `COMMIT TRANS` to the beginning of the trigger would that work?

Also, should `FOR EACH ROW` be added to this trigger, just in case multiple reports are saved by the database simultaneously?

**UPDATE**

I have since revised the code, as below:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[report_compare_trigger]
on [dbo].[report_test_to_user]
after insert

as
set xact_abort off
begin

set nocount on;

merge report_compare as target 
    using (select report_id from inserted) as source (report_id) 
    on (target.report_id = source.report_id)
    when not matched then insert (report_id) values (report_id);

if (select accession_id from report_compare where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted)) is null
    begin
        update report_compare
        set accession_id = id from accession_test
        where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted) and accession_test.report_id = (select report_id from inserted);
    end

update report_compare
    set report_compare.id_count = id_count + 1 
    where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted);

if (select date_opened from report_compare where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted)) is null
    begin
        update report_compare
        set date_opened = cre_time from report_test_section
        where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted) and report_test_section.report_id = (select report_id from inserted);
    end

if (select user_id from inserted) <> 'EmergencyDept'
    begin
        if (select users from report_compare where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted)) is null
            begin
                update report_compare
                set users = isnull(users, '') + user_id from inserted where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted)
            end
        else
            begin
update report_compare
        set users = isnull(users, '') + ', ' + user_id from inserted where report_compare.report_id = (select report_id from inserted)
            end
    end

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly offtopic perhaps but it sounds like you might benefit from [temporal tables](https://www.sqlshack.com/performing-a-sql-server-audit-using-system-versioned-temporal-tables/) - available from SQL Server 2016. SQL server also has **auditing** features so you don't have to completely reinvent the wheel.

> I tried the following code without success. Nothing was inserted into
>   dbo.report_compare and there were issues with the audit table
>   dbo.report_to_user while the trigger was running.

What kind of issues ?

Does that statement actually return a row ?

```
SELECT report_id
FROM inserted
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(report_id) 
FROM report_to_user 
GROUP BY report_id 
HAVING count(report_id) > 2);
```

Comment: I'll look into the auditing features, I didn't know about those, but we are using SQL 2008 so I think temporal tables may be out. As far as the kind of issues, information wasn't being written correctly to the table the trigger was set up on. End result was that reports weren't being signed off in the end user system. Once I removed the trigger everything was happy again, and if the reports were resigned by the end user those reports were fixed. So the trigger was blocking any forward progress.

Comment: I just tried that code substituting `from inserted` with `from report_to_user` (the table it would be coming from) as a test query, I got the error `Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'.` so something is inherently wrong with what i wrote there

Comment: something like this seems to work if i replace `from inserted` with a specific report id `select report_id, count(report_id) from report_to_user group by report_id having count(report_id) > 2 and report_id = 'xxxxx'`but now i'm reading you will get a mutation error if you read or write a table in an after insert trigger... so maybe this should be a before insert